# Some problems occurred in utils.py when reproducing AttnGAN

Tags: python-imaging-library

When I tried to reproduce the AttnGAN code, there was a problem with training DAMSM. The code shows

```
File "/home/ManiGAN-master/code/miscc/utils.py", line 145, in build_super_images
     PIL_att = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(one_map))
   File "/home/anaconda3/envs/pt/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2463, in fromarray
     raise TypeError("Cannot handle this data type")
TypeError: Cannot handle this data type
```

I tried a lot of PIL versions, but did anyone encounter the same problem? How to solve it? Thanks a lot!